# UdpClient.Receive() equivalent in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, udp, async-await, .net-core

Below is an extension I have written to provide a blocking Receive() call to the .NET Core `UdpClient` along the lines of what the .NET Framework provides. The intended use is to push this off into a thread that can be spun off to await data and continue execution when it receives it.

```
public static class UdpClientExtensions
{
    public static (IPEndPoint remoteEndpoint, byte[] buffer) Receive(this UdpClient udpClient)
    {
        return UdpClientExtensions.ReceiveAsync(udpClient).Result;
    }

    internal static async Task<(IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint, byte[] buffer)> ReceiveAsync(UdpClient udpClient)
    {
        UdpReceiveResult udpReceiveResult = await udpClient.ReceiveAsync();
        return (udpReceiveResult.RemoteEndPoint, udpReceiveResult.Buffer);
    }
}
```

Overall though this code feels convoluted to accomplish this and I fear I am not quite grasping the `async/await` concepts that have been added since I last actively developed with C#. Is this the proper way to create something like this or is my thinking outdated and I should approach this in a different manner?

Comment: Avoid blocking on `async` functions because your code can deadlock: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @Dai Really? That proper answer to this is put async in front of everything? ... Let me be a bit more clear in my disbelief. I need a blocking read, plain and simple. I have to stop and wait for data some where. I am not given an interface in .NET Core that isnt Async for reading data or I would be using that. It seems a bit odd that if i want to do networking in .NET Core via UdpClient that I have to prefix everything with async or risk getting context changing deadlocks. Which since these are console apps I do not think are an issue but I am looking general case in this particular question.

Comment: @Dai Ah, nevermind.. I found a comment from 3 months ago that explains this is a common, but odd, UI/ASP.NET deadlocking in reference to async/await syntax. Would the above cause a deadlock in that case? Yes.. But so would a bad await call on UdpClient.ReceiveAsync() as well if your UI was not already written to be Async... Thanks for the article I understand a bit more.. I still feel this  is a convoluted code flow to write 'wait until I receive data'.

Comment: Deadlock is caused by sync context switch, you can avoid that with `ConfigureAwait(false)` if you need a blocking call

Comment: @VMAtm It's better to explicitly use your own thread (ideally, from the thread-pool) then because `ConfigureAwait(false)` does not guarantee that a background or threadpool-thread will be used (technically, neither does the `LongRunning` task option either) - and in the event of thread-pool starvation your program will run suboptimally.

Comment: It only guarantees that no synch context will be restored. If OP doesn't need that, it probably will resolve his problem

Comment: @VMAtm As mentioned in the question above, this is meant to be spun off in its own thread.